# X-Forwarded-For in the request-ip package potential bug

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, http-headers, ip

I was reading the request-ip code. ([Link here](https://github.com/pbojinov/request-ip/blob/master/src%2Findex.js)) and I noticed that when dealing with the X-Forwarded-For part it is treated as if it will only be a string always. when in reality it's very possible that it can be an array of IPs, and when it wants to get client IP from X-Forwarded-For, it assumes that it is just a string of IPs concatenated with a ',' character

I expected it to join the IPs with a ',' character if it was an array, but that's not the case. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your code please

Comment: my fault, here is the link to their GitHub repo: https://github.com/pbojinov/request-ip/blob/master/src%2Findex.js

Comment: I don’t think x-forwarded-for can be an array as it’s a http header, and they are all strings.  Maybe you are using a library that splits it into an array?

Comment: I am using expressJS and when I try to use function available only for string, such as join, it gives me this error `Property 'join' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.
  Property 'join' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Strings do not have a [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method.